# How to call destructor in C # XNA

Tags: c#, xna, destructor

I have a object and simply want to destroy it on some event. How to call the destructor in XNA?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Set the object to `null` and the Garbage Collector will pick it up on it's next run.

As a side note, if the object is something that you create often (enemies, bullets etc..), then you may want to use a [pool](http://xnawiki.com/index.php?title=Generic_Resource_Pool) instead of deleting the object. This would mean that object is recycled, and thus, the garbage collector is called less often which will increase performance.

Comment: OMG, that is the last thing you want to do in .NET

Comment: foreach (Kour dym in smokeList)
            {
                dym.cas += gameTime.ElapsedGameTime;
                if (dym.cas > TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.5))
                {
                    dym = null;
                }
            }

Comment: @Nick Berardi - Could you explain why please since it seemingly warranted a downvote? Why is referencing small number of object to `null` and the recommendation of using a `pool`the last thing you want to do? @Nasgharet - What's not working? Also, `smokeList` sounds like a particle system. You should use pooling, not `null` on all objects if that's the case.

Comment: Because as @Nasgharet indicated setting an object to `null` does nothing in .NET memory wise, it was a common misconception brought over from the C and C++ days of some programmers. The only way to put an object on a Finalize process for the GC is to let it fall out of scope.

Comment: @Nashgharet the reason it is not working in your case is that the event handler is keeping the object in scope because the event is never being unbound from the object.  You need to call -= to remove the event before it will be collected.

Comment: @Nick Berardi - No, it doesn't have an immediate effect on memory. The question was to destroy the object (i.e. lose reference) in the game (since it's `XNA`). The IDisposable pattern is certainly valid for removal but OP wasn't concerned with memory removal, rather destroying of the object. Forcing the GC is careless in a realtime game (esp on XBox/WP7) and `pooling` is still better than `disposing`(common objs).There's no need to set as `null` from a memory perspective necessarily, but it helps when trying to remove an enemy from the game. When would a bullet go out of scope automatically?

Comment: See this example on my comment for how to use weak references instead of the strong references you are currently using with your event handler.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6269427/how-to-call-destructor-in-c-xna/6269573#6269573

Comment: @keyboardP What you are talking about is design considerations not the cleaning up of memory, and 2nd the example he gave will never free the `dym` object until the `gameTime` object was freed, because of the strong reference created by the event handler.  This is a common problem that event driven models cause, so even if you set it to `null` it will not got freed until `gameTime` is freed.

Comment: @Nick Berardi - I guess we cross-wired. I assumed the OP was asking it from a perspective of getting rid of an object from the game, not necessarily from the memory POV. That's why I suggested pooling, especially if your going to loop over the objects (chances are, there are numerous amount).

Comment: @keyboardP why do you think one even would ever wanted  to `destroy the object`? It is to do things that have to be done after the object disappeared — i.e. close network/file descriptors, and etc. AFAIK C# still have no a way to do this *(there's a workaround with IDisposable though, but it is very error-prone, because compiler doesn't even warns a programmer to use `using` with such classes)*.

Answer (score 3):

While your mileage may vary, my preference is to use `IDisposable` and `Dispose()` of objects I no longer need. This is esp. true when you are using unmanaged resources, but having the `Dispose()` set up declares intent.

See this resource on `GC.SuppressFinalize` for a good example of how to implement `IDisposable`.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.gc.suppressfinalize.aspx

Comment: In addition to just using Dispose, you can go ahead and follow the Disposable pattern so you can free up the object at will, but if it goes out of scope, it gets taken care of by the GC.

Answer (score 1):

Set reference to this object to `null`.

Answer (score 0):

After setting the object to `null`, if you want for some reason the object to be collected immediately, call `GC.Collect()`.

Comment: Not good generic advice. Calling GC.Collect does not guarantee it will immediately collect anyway and may actually end up creating more problems than it is worth.

Comment: @Gregory A Beamer From MSDN on `GC.Collect`: _"Forces an immediate garbage collection of all generations."_. Of course all depends on a situation whether `GC.Collect` should be called or not. E.g. if an object consumes a lot of memory which should be freed as fast as possible, `GC.Collect`is useful.

Comment: Let me ammend my hastily stated statement. GC not guuranteed to clean any objects up. I like Rico's rules for Garbage Collection: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ricom/archive/2004/11/29/271829.aspx

Answer (score 0):

What kind of object? If is an Disposable/IDisposable you should call object.Dispose()
Otherwise, you can just use object=null, and it will be 'cleaned' automatically. This is not C you're working in ;)

If your 'object' is actually a complex class or something with more objects in it, you might want to consider making it an IDisposable class.

Answer (score 0):

If the object holds any unmanaged resources then implement `IDisposable` (and use `using` or call `Dispose()` on it when you're done with it).

If it doesn't hold unmanaged resources then the garbage collector will claim it "at some point" when there are no more references to it.

GC.Collect() will make the garbage collector collect and it will "destroy" your object if there are no references to it. This is not a very good idea since it has performance implications (it takes time and promotes other objects into a higher generation making them last longer in memory before being reclaimed).

Why do you need the object destroyed at a certain fixed time?

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is call [`GC.SuppressFinalize()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.gc.suppressfinalize.aspx) if you are handling the cleanup yourself...  Usually you use `GC.SuppressFinalize()` within an `IDisposable` class.  See this code example for the common use of `IDisposable`:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.gc.suppressfinalize.aspx

If you really need to have it Garbage Collected right away:

```cs
var myObj = new MyObject();

// This object will be cleaned up by the Dispose method.
// Therefore, you should call GC.SupressFinalize to
// take this object off the finalization queue 
// and prevent finalization code for this object
// from executing a second time.
GC.SuppressFinalize(myObj);
```

But I caution you that you should really let the object go out of scope, and let the GC collect the objects naturally. The .NET runtime is very efficient at managing memory as long as you don't try to do it's job.

**EDIT**

After reviewing the comments, I see you forgot to leave an important piece of information, in that you were binding the object in question to other objects methods. This means that the object that you are trying to finalize is not going to finalize until the method used to watch the event has finalized, thus keeping around a ton of extra objects in memory.

What you can do to break this strong reference is use an object called [`WeakReference`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.weakreference.aspx). Or use lambdas to to break the strong references.

See this for an example of using a WeakReference
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.weakreference.aspx

Or you can do something like this:

```
dym.cas += (x, y, z) => gameTime.ElapsedGameTime(x,y,z);
```

instead of

```
dym.cas += gameTime.ElapsedGameTime;
```